# Show directly that if $E_1\geqslant E_2\geqslant\dots$, then $E_i\rightarrow \bigwedge E_i$ strongly.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Suppose that $H$ is a Hilbert space and we have sequence (or net) of non-increasing orthogonal projections
$$E_1\geqslant E_2\geqslant E_3\geqslant\dots$$
Then we have also an operator $\bigwedge E_i$ which is a projection on space $\bigcap E_i(H)$.

> **Problem**. Show that $E_i\rightarrow \bigwedge E_i$ strongly **without using** orthogonal projections $\bot$.

In Kadison/Ringrose book (2.5.6) and (2.5.7) are devoted to this problem. (2.5.6) shows that for non-decreasing sequence (net) $E_i\rightarrow \bigvee E_i$ strongly and then (2.5.7) uses $\bot$ to show our case.

**Why do I want avoid $\bot$?**

- In general, proving things for $\bigwedge E_i$ is easier then for $\bigvee E_i$. Thus, this case is somehow different. I wonder why it is so.
- <s>Moreover, in a Banach space we can also compare projections (abandoning orthogonality) and talk about $\bigwedge E_i$. So how about strong convergence in such spaces. Does this result still holds?</s> (Edit: This is invalid, because $\bigwedge E_i$ does not make sence)

$\require{cancel}$

Comment: ??? You want to prove something about orthogonal projections without "using" orthogonal projections?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Objects that appear in problem do not use the notion of orthogonality (that is the point).

Comment: Huh? The notion of "orthogonal projection" does not use the notion of orthogonality?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich You are right in this. But still, the proof of the fact that non-decreasing net $E_i$ convergens strongly to $\bigvee E_i$ avoids $\bot$ completely and could be applied to arbitrary projections on Banach spaces. So the problem is still well formulated and I wish to know the answer.

Comment: Ok, when you say there's a result for Banach spaces I get an idea what you''re after. Give me a hint: How is the result for an increasing sequence in a Banach space even _stated_? (My best guess: If $||P_j||=1$, $P_j^2=P_j$ and $P_jP_{j+1}=P_{j+1}P_j=P_{j+1}$ then $(P_jx)$ converges. Is that it?)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I think you got me. In Banach spaces $\bigvee P_j$ and $\bigwedge$ may not be well defined, because specifing a close subspace of Banach space does not determine a projection. Thus, my claim about analogous result in Banach spaces is false. Thx.

Comment: Hmm. In the future it would probably be best if you avoid saying that something can be proved unless it can actually be proved...